# What does .decode return in swift 4?

Tags: swift, decode

When you call `.decode()` to decode a struct, what exactly does it return?
I have look it up on the Apple Documentation, but all it says is "native format into in-memory representations." But what does this mean? Can anyone help me?

I'm asking this because my app is crashing when I get a null value from the JSON data, from this line of code:

```
let plantData = try decoder.decode([Plants].self, from: data)
```

Here is my `struct`:

```
struct Plants: Codable {

    let date: String
    let monthlyAVG: String?

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {

        case date = "Date"
        case monthlyAVG = "30_Day_MA_MMBTU"
    }
}
```

And Here is my Parsing code:

```
func parseJson() {
    let url = URL(string: ebr_String)

    // Load the URL
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        // If there are any errors don't try to parse it, show the error
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { print(error!); return }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
            let plantData = try decoder.decode([Plants].self, from: data)
            print(plantData)
```

And Here is just a snippet of the information I am getting back:

```
MorrowTabbedApp.Plants(date: "2018-02-22", monthlyAVG: Optional("1210.06")), MorrowTabbedApp.Plants(date: "2018-02-23", monthlyAVG: nil)]
```

Here is the snippet of JSON from the web:

```
[
    {"Date":"2018-02-21","30_Day_MA_MMBTU":"1210.06"},
    {"Date":"2018-02-22","30_Day_MA_MMBTU":"1210.06"},
    {"Date":"2018-02-23","30_Day_MA_MMBTU":null}
]
```

Comment: This Specific line of code that I have here: let PlantData = try decoder.decode([Plants].self, from: data). I'm confused as to what its getting back

Comment: @Gina Please [edit] your question with all relevant details instead of posting information in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The `decode` method of `JSONDecoder` is a "generic" method. It returns an instance of whatever type you specified in the first parameter of the method. In your case, it returns a `[Plants]`, i.e. a `Array<Plants>`, i.e. a Swift array of `Plants` instances.

If it's crashing because of a `null` value in your JSON, then you have to identify what was null, whether it was appropriate to be null, and if so, make sure that any `Plants` properties associated with values that might be `null` should be optionals.

---

Given your updated answer with code snippets, I'd suggest:

```
// Personally, I'd call this `Plant` as it appears to represent a single instance

struct Plant: Codable {
    let date: String
    let monthlyAVG: String?   // Or you can use `String!` if you don't want to manually unwrap this every time you use it

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case date = "Date"
        case monthlyAVG = "30_Day_MA_MMBTU"
    }
}
```

And:

```
do {
    let plantData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Plant].self, from: data)
        .filter { $0.monthlyAVG != nil }

    print(plantData)
} catch let parseError {
    print(parseError)
}
```

Note the `filter` line which selects only those occurrences for which `monthlyAVG` is not `nil`.

---

A couple of other suggestions:

1. Personally, if you could, I'd rather see the web service designed to only return the values you want (those with an actual `monthlyAVG`) and then change the `monthlyAVG` property to not be an optional. But that's up to you.
2. If `monthlyAVG` is really a numeric average, I'd change the web service to not return it as a string at all, but as a number without quotes. And then change the property of `Plant` to be `Double` or whatever.
3. You could, if you wanted, change the `date` property to be a `Date` and then use `dateDecodingStrategy` to convert the string to a `Date`:

   ```
   struct Plant: Codable {
       let date: Date
       let monthlyAVG: String?

       enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
           case date = "Date"
           case monthlyAVG = "30_Day_MA_MMBTU"
       }
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   do {
       let decoder = JSONDecoder()
       let formatter = DateFormatter()
       formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
       formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
       decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

       let plantData = try decoder.decode([Plant].self, from: data)
           .filter { $0.monthlyAVG != nil }

       print(plantData)
   } catch let parseError {
       print(parseError)
   }
   ```

   You might do this if, for example, you wanted the x-axis of your chart to actually represent time rather than an evenly spaced set of data points.

Comment: Yes. I have found the null value and I would like to change it to zero or delete it completely if possible. I do have the property for this specific value to be String?. I was thinking of passing this parsed data into another function and looping through it to check for null values and then just delete them if possible.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question. Thanks for being patient. I am very new to Swift and wrapping my brain around it is proving difficult.

Comment: @Gina - OK, your code looks good. It doesn't look like this is crashing. Are you just saying that you'd like to filter out all occurrences where `"30_Day_MA_MMBTU"` is `null`? Or are you asking how to deal with those `Optional(...)` references?

Comment: Yes. Filter out all the occurrences where "30_Day_MA_MMBTU" is null. The values are supposed to be a number as a String and I'm assuming I would have to parse them into integers to use them because I have to later enter these numbers on a real time graph that I have already made using iOS Charts. Now that I think about it, I would like to just delete the null values completely because I would not want 0's on the graph.

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it! I'm going to review the code and see if I can implement your suggestions in my code.